# Why Compose Card not clickable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview, android-compose-card

I am trying to use jetpack compose 1.0.0-beta08. If I add clickable to Text it works but only text field ripples so what is the problem on Card click ?

```
@Composable
fun FoodCategoryChip(
    text: String,
    onClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = { onClick(text) }),//this is not working
        elevation = 8.dp,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
            color = Color.Black,
        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Starting from [`1.0.0-beta08`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.0.0-beta08) with the `Card` you have to use the version with the **`onClick`** parameter:

> BEHAVIOUR-BREAKING: Card now consumes clicks, making clicks added via Card(Modifier.clickable) to be a no-op. Please, use new experimental overload of a Card that accepts onClick.

```
Card( 
    onClick = { /*...*/ },
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp),
    elevation = 8.dp,
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
) {
    //..
}
```