# Ignore a click on Jetpack Compose Card, but catch it in the containing layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-cardview

I had an XML layout for CardView that I changed to Jetpack Compose Card.
This Card is included in another clickable larger XML layout that has other items around that card.

In the old CardView layout the onClick wasn't handled, and clicking on the card was just like clicking anywhere else on the larger layout.

Now when the card is Jetpack Compose, the click is separated from the larger layout, and by default the card is not clickable at all. when I add clickable modifier, then the card is clickable but separated from the larger layout and is not handled by that layout.

How can I make the Jetpack Compose Card behave the same as a regular CardView that has no click action of its own?
I want the entire layout be clickable no matter if the click is on the card or anywhere else.

I tried setting

```
  Modifier.clickable(
            interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
            indication = null,
            onClick = {}
        )
```

But it didn't help, the card is still not clickable, only when clicking outside the card then the desired action is triggered.

Using `onClick = { }` makes the card clickable, but separated from the rest of the layout.

I can't put it inside Box, because the card is included in an XML layout

Comment: Starting from 1.0.0-beta08 with the Card you have to use the version with the onClick parameter. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67932603/why-compose-card-not-clickable/67932902#67932902

Comment: It makes the card clickable, not the whole layout behind. I need the card not to block the click, but also not to catch it. I need the layout that contains the card and the rest of the items handle the click

Comment: Post your code pls

Comment: Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
        backgroundColor = LocalColors.current.Grey900
    )

Comment: I see it can either block clicks, or catch them. I want them not to be blocked, but handled by the containing layout as in a regular "old" cardView

Comment: It is not clear what is your code.If you have a clickable box, and inside a not clickable Card, all the layout is clickable

Comment: I have an old XML layout, and only the Card component is Compose at the moment

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a clickable parent layout just use:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Box(Modifier
    //...
    .clickable(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = LocalIndication.current,
        onClick = { /** doSomething() **/}
    )
    //.padding(4.dp)
) {
    Card(){
        //Card content
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! can it be done somehow when the parent layout is an old XML layout and not Compose?

Comment: I have a similar issue but with a child `Chip` composable. And this doesn't seem to work from that. I can't seem to stop the `Chip` grabbing the click.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if a `TextField` is the composable child.